# how can i call coldfusion component file from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I want to know about coldfusion to ajax call so that i can display data without reloading ma page. Take simple example. Adding two numbers by clicking a button. For that i need two input elements and a button and it should display in the same page. What i'm trying to do is when i get input from a user the moment they click i need answer without reloading a page. So i used component file and written function for my scenario..and i call my component through ajax. But i'm getting error on my stuff. Let me show what i did.

Coldfusion code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Adding two numbers</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <!--two numbers to add when clicking a button it will show my result in display-->
            FIRST NUMBER<input type="text" id="a" name="a" >
            SECOND NUMBER<input type="text" id="b" name="b">
            <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="add">
            ANS<input type="text" name="display" id="display" readonly>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function(f) {
                // Next, we will be needing the value of the textfield in order to pass it to ColdFusion.
                var variableToPass = $("input#a").val();
                var variableToPass1 = $("input#b").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "add.cfc?method=add&returnformat=json",
                    data: {
                        a: variableToPass,
                        b: variableToPass1
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#display").val(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

I saved this as add.cfm and here is my component file ie(add.cfc)

```
<cfcomponent>
     <cffunction name="add" access="remote" returntype="numeric">
         <cfargument name="a">
         <cfargument name="b">
         <cfset c=a+b>
         <cfreturn c>
     </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

While running my code...i throws error that type errors and more warnings...please help me

Comment: change the submit button id to click currently it is 'button'

Comment: now too same issueeeee....

Comment: why you have returnFormat= json when you just return numeric data?

Comment: 'more warnings'? What exactly are the error messages you are getting? Are they ColdFusion errors or JS errors? Add them to the question.

Comment: mm yep what u r saying  is right

Comment: I'm getting js errors only

Comment: Please do not *describe* the errors, just add the full error message(s) to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35666753/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used div instead of input element and it was working fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Adding two numbers</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <!--two numbers to add when clicking a button it will show my result in display-->
            FIRST NUMBER<input type="text" id="a" name="a" >
            SECOND NUMBER<input type="text" id="b" name="b">
            <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="add">
            ANS<div id="display"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function(f) {
                var variableToPass = $("input#a").val();
                var variableToPass1 = $("input#b").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "add.cfc?method=add&returnformat=json",
                    data: {
                        a: variableToPass,
                        b: variableToPass1
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $("#display").html(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't really see why this is the accepted answer since @rrk [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35667136/7451109) the answer closer to the original code.

Comment: I used div instead of input element so it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Change returntype `number` to `numeric`. Because there is not return type `number` for coldfusion function.

```
<cffunction name="add" access="remote" returntype="numeric">
```

Note in your example instead of `$("#click")` you should use `$("#button")`.

Then use `val()` instead of `html()`, because that is how you add a value to an `input` field.

```
$("#display").val(result);
```

Comment: I didnt see any any error in coldfusion server...and i'm not getting any output in my view too...bt when i see firefor firebug i can see typedef error and lots of warnings

Comment: @SowmyaSow actually I did, it is working for me. are you sure the ajax call is happening?

Comment: yep ajax call is happening...Actually i'm a fresher i dunno a lot since i'm learning daily...okay i have to know whether i have to store my cfc file anywhere in my coldfusion

Comment: see Rejith ... when i'm entering a input in view itself i'm getting dat error...such as type def and more warnings

Comment: @SowmyaSow Are add.cfm and add.cfc in the same folder?

Comment: yep it's in samefolder

Comment: Now can you add `<cfdump var="#1+2#">` in add.cfm and see if the result appears in the page?

Comment: Any other suggestion other than this

Comment: @SowmyaSow Not really.

Comment: mm okay...do we have any free online editor for coldfusion

Comment: @SowmyaSow I normally use Notepad++ with coldfusion plugin. Then there is Brackets, cfeclipse etc.

Comment: how can i install coldfusion plugins is it free??

Comment: for free Cold Fusion code editors, your google search string is "coldfusion free code editor".

Comment: @SowmyaSow in notepad++ it is free. install NP++, then got to `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager` then select `Coldfusion Lexer` from the list and then click install.

Comment: my error is                   XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Sowmi/Desktop/add.cfc?method=add&returnformat=plain&a=23&b=45. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.send @ jquery-latest.min.js:4m.extend.ajax @ jquery-latest.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ add.cfm:23m.event.dispatch @ jquery-latest.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-latest.min.js:3...